# Executing conditional scenarios in $(document).ready() depending on the value of ViewBag

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a master page and a `$(document).ready()` handler in it. Depending on the actual page that will be rendered the `ViewBag.Post` will either be 'true' or 'false'. If it is set to true I will perform an AJAX operation when the handler is triggered, otherwise not. But the `ViewBag` cannot be called inside javascript code, or is it?

How else can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in document ready method u can write it like

```
var _isAjax = '@ViewBag.Post';
if(_isAjax)
{
   //do ajax
}
//do other stuff
```

Comment: You should add that these lines should be in the master page view (cshtml/vbhtml/aspx), and not in any JS.

Comment: yep exactly, in js files u don't have access to server variables

Answer (score 0):

```
<body perform="@(ViewBag.YourValue ? "Ajax":string.Empty)">
...

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($("body").attr("perform")=="Ajax"){
        $.ajax({yourajaxparmeters});
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why incur extra overhead with HTML parsing when you could just be assigning the value directly into script?

Comment: @Anthony Sottile: because when the script is in js file, there is no access to ViewBag

Comment: Yeah but you can just have a script block?

Comment: @Anthony Sottile: you can, but if, later, you want to deport this block on a javascript file you have to add additional attribute to your HTML

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but it seems quite a bit more maintainable to keep one line of dynamically written JS in a script block and do the rest of the work elsewhere (if needed).  Attaching it to an HTML element is a somewhat shifty situation and is especially difficult to document and debug (even moreso if your javascript file is now detached from the page).

Comment: @Anthony Sottile: if you look how asp.net mvc do unobtrusive javascript validation it is like this. if the attribute are well self-describing it is easier to maintain that to have lot of inline scripts, and moreover you can cache your javascript file.

Comment: well then shouldn't the attributes be prefixed by `data-` if you are going for the HTML5 specs?

Comment: @Anthony Sottile: of course and it is better to also prefix it to avoid collision with other script libraries